# Is there any way to print all pages of a Cross Tab Crystal Report through the .NET Crystal API?

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

We are printing our Crystal Reports via the Crystal .NET API PrintToPrinter method. Recently it was discovered that when printing Cross Tab reports (reports that span multiple pages horizontally), only the first page is printed and the other "virtual" pages are not. We can preview the Reports fine in the .NET Crystal Report Viewer control and they show the wide report we expect, but when we print using the PrintToPrinter() method the output is definitely not what we just saw in that preview. Only the first page prints and you can see the beginning of what should be the second page cut off.

When printing through the Crystal Designer, the other pages are printed as expected. Also of note is that when we print via the "Print" button on the .NET Crystal Report Viewer control, it also prints all of the expected pages (they're jut not paged as well as when printing through the Crystal Designer).

Only the PrintToPrinter method (both overrides) seems to print only the first page of the Cross Tab Report.

I'm wondering if there's just setting I need to be setting programmatically to make this work or if I have just missed somewhere out there that this is a known issue with the Crystal .NET API?